# Efficient Way to Find Index of Object in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which I fill with objects of type Integer in a serial fashion (i.e. one-by-one) from the end of the ArrayList (i.e. using the method add(object)). Every time I do this, the other objects in the ArrayList are of course left-shifted by one index.

In my code I want to find the index of a random object in the ArrayList. I want to avoid using the indexOf method because I have a very big ArrayList and the looping will take an enormous amount of time. Are there any workarounds? Some idea how to keep in some data structure maybe the indexes of the objects that are in the ArrayList?

EDIT: Apparently my question was not clear or I had a missunderstanding of the arraylist.add(object) method (which is also very possible!). What I want to do is to have something like a sliding-window with objects being inserted at one end of the arraylist and dropped from the other, and as an object is inserted to one end the others are shifted by one index. I could use arraylist.add(0, object) for inserting the objects from the left of the arraylist and right-shifting each time the previous objects by one index, but making a google search I found that this is very processing-intensive operation - O(N) if I remember right. Thus, I thought "ok, let's insert the objects from the right-end of the arraylist, no problem!", assuming that still each insertion will move the previous objects by one index (to the left this time).

Also when I use the term "index" I simply mean the position of the object in the ArrayList - maybe there is some more formall term "index" which means something different.

Comment: Use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` to store indices.

Comment: *If* you are adding them in some particular order, could you maybe use the size of the list to determine the index of a given item?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "Every time I do this, the other objects in the ArrayList are of course left-shifted by one index". If you are adding to the end, the indices stay the same.

Comment: @SLaks         That was my initial idea too. But since the indexes are changing by 1 every time I put an object in my ArrayList, I will have to update them in the HashMap too. This implies that I will have to loop the map in order to set the value of the previous index to value += 1. Thus I will have the same performance cost as with the indexOf method of the ArrayList.

Comment: As long as the indices of existing objects aren't changing (i.e. you are always adding to the end of the array), I also recommend maintaining a `Map<Object,Integer>` parallel to the array. You will have to update the map if you remove an object. Another alternative, which may be appropriate for you even though it breaks some conceptual OOP boundaries, could be to add an index field to the objects themselves (if you have control over it). Update after remove similar to using a map. Then you can directly retrieve indices from the object.

Comment: `But since the indexes are changing by 1 every time I put an object in my ArrayList` Huh? Adding to the end doesn't change anything else

Comment: @Whymarrh      I don't understand what you mean. Maybe I am wrong, but I think that if I put, let's say, the object 5 at the end of my ArrayList (i.e. at index arraylist.size()-1) using arraylist.add(object) and then I put the object 3 at the end of my ArrayList, then the object 5 will be moved one index left at the index arraylist.size()-2.

Comment: @PeterHiggs The indexes will only be changing if you are inserting in the middle or beginning of the array. Do you have to do this? Could you append instead? Or, do you add all objects prior to having to find any? If you must insert objects but you do all insertions first, you can build the map after all objects are inserted.

Comment: @PeterHiggs you are correct about the indices changing. I didn't understand the question correctly.

Comment: @PeterHiggs It's true that an existing object index would change from `arraylist.size()-X` to `arraylist.size()-X-1`, but that's because `size()` changes, not because the index changes. You are thinking about the index relative to `arraylist.size()` for some reason. The index itself doesn't change.

Comment: ok, probably I had understand something wrong at the first place. I will edit my question.

Comment: Ahh; I see your edit. I am going to delete my answer and see if I can update it.

Comment: @PeterHiggs BTW, "index" is the correct term. The source of our confusion in your original question was that you didn't mention that you were removing elements from the front of the list each time you added one to the back, so your statement that the indexes were shifted after each add was lacking context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options. Here are the two basic options:

1. You can maintain a `Map<Object,Integer>` that holds indexes, in parallel to the array. When you append an element to the array you can just add it to the map. When you remove an element from the beginning you will have to iterate through the entire map and subtract one from every index.
2. If it's appropriate for your situation and the `Map` does not meet your performance requirements, you could add an `index` field to your objects and store the index directly when you add it to the array. When you remove an element from the beginning you will have to iterate through all objects in the list and subtract one from their index. Then you can obtain the index in constant time given an object.

These still have the performance hit of updating the indexes after a remove. Now, after you choose one of these options, you can avoid having to iterate through the map / list to update after removal if you make a simple improvement:

Instead of storing the index of each object, store a count of the total number of objects added so far. Then to get the actual index, simply subtract the count value of the first object from the value of the one you are looking for. E.g. when you add:

```
add a to end;
a.counter = counter++;
remove first object;
```

(The initial value of `counter` when starting the program doesn't really matter.) Then to find an object "x":

```
index = x.counter - first object.counter;
```

Whether you store `counter` as a new field or in a map is up to you. Hope that helps.

By the way; a linked list will have better performance when removing object from the front of the list, but worse when accessing an object by index. It may be more appropriate depending on your balance of add/remove vs. random access (if you only care about the index but never actually need to retrieve an object by index, random access performance doesn't matter). If you really need to optimize further you could consider using a fixed-capacity ring buffer instead (back inserts, front removes, and random access will all be O(1)).

Of course, option 3 is to reconsider your algorithm at a higher level; perhaps there is a way to accomplish the behavior you are seeking that does not require finding the objects in the list.

Comment: The counter idea seems really good, I was thinking also something like that (calculating the position shifts). I will try to implement it, thank you!

Comment: Worked perfectly! A million thanks! Too bad I have reputation smaller than 15 and I can't upvote, but if I could I would give you +100000000000!!!

Comment: Finally, >15 reputation, thus +1 for you!

Comment: I don't get the algorithm, what does 'first object' refer to?

Comment: @JShattu The first object in the list.